# Wave functions without normalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability, normalization

I'm working on a problem where we find the probability of finding a particle between $a/4$, and $3a/4$. The particle is confined between $0$ and $a$.

Normally I would attack this by normalising the wave function, solving for $A$, and then using that value in the next steps to find the probability between a given range.
However, I have been given an equation without the A in the wave function:

$$ \Psi(x,t) = \sin(\pi x/a) e^{-i\omega t}  $$

Initially I just added $A$ myself and normalised the wave function, then carried on, and I get an answer that makes sense. However I have been told that we take $A=1$, and don't need to normalise the function. Assuming that $A = 1$, and then using it through the rest of the steps I find a probability that still includes $a$ in it, rather than a numerical value.

Can anyone confirm the correct process when it is implied that $A = 1$?

Comment: $A\ne 1$: you need to normalize properly.  In fact $A$ depends on $a$.

Comment: If you choose not to normalise the state you can still go through with the calculation, but there isn't really any reason not to. If $A$ is defined as "the constant which normalises the state $\Psi(x,t)$" then you cannot arbitrarily set it equal to $1$, who told you that?

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, this is what I thought and confirms the outcome of either method. It was my lecturer that said it wasn't necessary, so perhaps he misunderstood what I was asking.

In this case, do you agree that I should add the A myself, and then normalise as usual?

Thanks!

Comment: The difference between normalising and not normalising is that at the end of your calculation the total probability of getting one of the possible outcomes of your measurement won't be $1$. In this case it will be $a/2$, which is harder to interpret. @jstook

Comment: Thanks so much @Charlie, I just realised I could leave the A off, and chuck that integral over the same integral from 0 to a as a fraction and get the same answer as inserting A myself and normalising. I've emailed my lecturer again to see where the misunderstanding is! 
Cheers, much appreciated.

Comment: @jstook Normalisation is done purely for convenience. The state $\Psi(x,t)$ and the state $\alpha\Psi(x,t)$ represent the *exact same* physical state, so we can rescale our wavefunction however we like and the underlying physics doesn't change. It is usually preferable to choose this scaling factor such that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\Psi(x,t)|^2\text dx=1$. This means that if we integrate over some smaller region and get a value of $0.5$, we immediately know there is a $50\%$ chance of finding the particle here, without having to ask "$0.5$ out of what?".

Comment: Again, thankyou @Charlie. I hadn't thought of it like that, the scaling factor part that is. Setting it to 1 always made sense, of course, but I'd taken A to be only an amplitude, as we learn during classical physics, rather than  a scaling factor. I'm actually glad I've had this problem as it's joined a couple of dots I didn't know need joining!